# What can I do to visualize my dataframe in a proper way?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, plotly, combinations

I have a dataframe in python that consists of two columns [Combinations] and [counts], the dataframe is 16369 rows, so there are 16369 combinations.
The combinations column consist of different combinations of departments (there are 14 different departments) working together on projects and the counts column is the amount of how much they worked together. There are about 8191 rows with 0 as counts.
I was wondering what the proper way would be to plot such a dataframe, I was thinking of a heatmap but this wont works because of all the unique values within the combinations column. How can I properly (preferably in something like plotly) plot this?

| Combinations | counts |
| --- | --- |
| A,B | 68 |
| C,A | 64 |
| F,C | 63 |
| F,L | 63 |
| E,A | 60 |
| B,A | 57 |
| Q,L | 56 |
| A,B,C | 55 |
| L,N | 54 |
| C,L,A,C | 53 |
| A,F,B | 52 |
| F,H | 51 |
| C,V | 50 |
| Q,F | 50 |
| Z,X | 49 |
| C,X | 49 |
| A,P | 49 |
| K,Q | 49 |
| R,S | 49 |

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to explore plotting these as sociograms? It seems like social network analysis will be an apt way to visualise the different relationships the departments have with each other.

You can try looking at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/social-network-analysis-from-theory-to-applications-with-python-d12e9a34c2c7) for some inspiration. coursera has some [courses](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-social-network-analysis#syllabus) you can explore too.